# Extract specific part of String

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty new to VBA, but not programming in general. I am trying to make a macro in VBA that formats the model name of a list of phone names to something manageable. E.g. I want the following name:

> P10, 12,9 cm (5.1"), 4 GB, 64 GB, 20 MP

To be formatted as

> P10 5.1" 64 GB

I have succeeded in extracting the first two elements of the formatted name using `Split` and `Mid`.

This is some of my code for the first two parts:

```
'First part of format
firstPart = Trim(Split(modelName, ",")(0))
Debug.Print formattedModelName

'Second part of format
openPos = InStr(modelName, "(")
closePos = InStr(modelName, ")")

secondPart = Mid(modelName, openPos + 1, closePos - openPos - 1)
```

My question is how to go about extracting the `64 GB` and not the `4 GB`.
I tried iterating through all characters and saving the last 5 characters to see if they matched what I wanted. But there must be a better way.

I would appreciate any help,
Thank you very much

**EDIT**

Here is another example of an input and the output as requested:
Input:

> iPhone iPhone SE, 10,2 cm (4"), 640 x 1136 pixel, 16 GB, 12 MP, iOS 9, Sort, Grå

Expected Output:

> iPhone iPhone SE 4" 16 GB

Comment: can you explain why 64 gb and not 4 gb.  Is it the second from the end, the second after the `()`?  How will excel know which to return?

Comment: The `64 GB` represents the storage of the phone, which has to be included in the name. This is always two digits which I think can be used to distinguish between `4 GB`. It is always after the `()` but the `4 GB` isn't always included.

Comment: Will there always be a space between the size and "GB" or "MP"?

Comment: Yes, there will always be a space between the value and the "GB" and "MP"

Comment: Can you please add more examples of the input and expected output?

Comment: Will the storage number always be the biggest there or is there a chance the MP number will be bigger? Also will there always be a storage number and will there always be comma's between the sections?

Comment: The MP number will never be bigger, however, sometimes pixels are included. E.g. "1136 x 640 pixel", and so the "64 GB" isn't the largest number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using RegEx to extract the values and using the last one.  Just add a reference to the library:  "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5".  Then you can do this..

```
Option Explicit

Public Function xx()
Dim modelName As String
Dim firstPart As String
Dim Pattern As String
Dim GBString As String
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim finalName As String
Dim matches As MatchCollection

Let modelName = "P10, 12,9 cm (5.1""), 4 GB, 64 GB, 20 MP"
firstPart = Trim(Split(modelName, ",")(0))


With regEx
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "[0-9]+ GB"
End With

Set matches = regEx.Execute(modelName)

If matches.Count > 0 Then
    GBString = matches(matches.Count)
Else
    GBString = "<unknown GB>"
End If

finalName = firstPart + GBString

End Function
```

Comment: You're pattern also picks up 4 GB.  Change to `.Pattern = "[0-9]{2,} GB"` to pick up 2 or more digits before the GB.  See [example](https://regexr.com/40to9)

Comment: That would work mostly but there are phones coming out now with over 10 GB of RAM which means they would still be picked before the storage GB. It depends on what types of phones @Fehrnovic has in his sheet.

Comment: @Taazar - Good point. Try this pattern to match the last occurrence: `.Pattern = "([0-9]+ GB)(?!.*[0-9]{2,} GB)"`  See [this link](https://regexr.com/40tq2) for example.  I added a new test line with RAM over 2 digits.

Comment: Thank you so much to all you guys, this helped a ton :)

Answer (score 4):

Try,

```
Option Explicit

Function oneTwoThree(str As String)

    Dim vals As Variant

    vals = Split(str, ",")

    oneTwoThree = Join(Array(vals(0), _
                             Split(Split(vals(2), "(")(1), ")")(0), _
                             Trim(vals(4 + (InStr(1, vals(4), "gb", vbTextCompare) = 0)))), " ")

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Problem is as `@Fehrnovic` has said that 4GB may not always be there and in a case like that this code will grab the 20 MP instead.

Comment: @Taazar, thanks for the heads up; adjusted above to suit.

Comment: That fix does help for some but it means that if the storage value is stored in the 4th section/`vals(3)` or before then it will be missed by your code.

Comment: Parsing text requires a finite number of conditions/criteria/ You can't keep piling on additional scenarios.

Comment: Yes the screenshot is real, not photoshopped.

Comment: Terribly sorry, turns out when I copied the code over I missed a bit at the end. Again I'm very sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try the next segment of code:

```
Dim modelName As String: modelName = "P10, 12,9 cm (5.1""), 4 GB, 64 GB, 20 MP"
Dim data() As String: data = Split(modelName, ",")
Dim firstPart As String
Dim secondPart As String
Dim thirdPart As String

firstPart = Trim(data(0))
secondPart = Trim(Replace(Mid(data(2), InStr(data(2), "(") + 1), ")", ""))
thirdPart = Trim(data(4))


MsgBox firstPart & " " & secondPart & " " & thirdPart
```

You have to be very careful about the delimiter data substring. For example, if your main text is `P10, 12 cm (5.1"), 4 GB, 64 GB, 20 MP` the code doesn't work anymore. Assuming you always have a comma and a space between data elements you could write instead:

```
Dim modelName As String: modelName = "P10, 12,9 cm (5.1""), 4 GB, 64 GB, 20 MP"
Dim data() As String: data = Split(modelName, ", ")
Dim firstPart As String
Dim secondPart As String
Dim thirdPart As String

firstPart = Trim(data(0))
secondPart = Trim(Replace(Mid(data(1), InStr(data(1), "(") + 1), ")", ""))
thirdPart = Trim(data(3))

MsgBox firstPart & " " & secondPart & " " & thirdPart
```

And it will always work.

If the element `4 MB` is not always present do the following:

```
Dim modelName As String: modelName = "P10, 12,9 cm (5.1""), 4 GB, 64 GB, 20 MP"
Dim data() As String: data = Split(modelName, ", ")
Dim firstPart As String
Dim secondPart As String
Dim thirdPart As String

firstPart = Trim(data(0))
secondPart = Trim(Replace(Mid(data(1), InStr(data(1), "(") + 1), ")", ""))

Select Case InStr(modelName, "4 GB")
    Case 0
        thirdPart = Trim(data(2))
    Case Else
        thirdPart = Trim(data(3))
End Select

MsgBox firstPart & " " & secondPart & " " & thirdPart
```

UPDATE:

I think now I got what you want exactly. I tried the next code with the three examples you gave us on your question and it worked (the problem was I didn't understand that you wanted the last data value before `MD` value.

```
Dim modelName As String
Dim data() As String
Dim firstPart As String
Dim secondPart As String
Dim thirdPart As String

modelName = "P10, 12,9 cm (5.1""), 4 GB, 64 GB, 20 MP"
data = Split(modelName, ", ")
firstPart = Trim(data(0))
secondPart = Trim(Replace(Mid(data(1), InStr(data(1), "(") + 1), ")", ""))
thirdPart = Trim(data(Application.Match("*MP", data, 0) - 2))

MsgBox firstPart & " " & secondPart & " " & thirdPart
```

You could try with

```
modelName = "P10, 12,9 cm (5.1""), 64 GB, 20 MP"
```

or with

```
modelName = "iPhone iPhone SE, 10,2 cm (4""), 640 x 1136 pixel, 16 GB, 12 MP, iOS 9, Sort, Grå"
```

It will always give you the answer.

Comment: Problem is as @Fehrnovic has said that 4GB may not always be there and in a case like that this code will grab the 20 MP instead

Comment: Thank you, but this only works when the `4 GB` is present. This is not always the case and so the `20 MP` is extracted instead. But using an array like that seems like a good idea

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function I have made that should always work.

For dealing with the issue of getting the correct storage value it goes through each section separated by commas and looks for "GB" and then it keeps track of the largest value in one of these sections, which must then be the storage value.

```
Public Function FormatName(Inp As String) As String

    Dim ArrInp As Variant, i As Integer, Temp As String

    ArrInp = Split(Trim(Inp), ",")
    FormatName = ArrInp(0) & " " & Mid(Inp, InStr(Inp, "(") + 1, InStr(Inp, ")") - InStr(Inp, "(") - 1)

    For i = 1 To UBound(ArrInp)
        If InStr(UCase(ArrInp(i)), "GB") <> 0 And Val(ArrInp(i)) > a Then
            Temp = ArrInp(i)
        End If
    Next
    FormatName = FormatName & Temp

End Function
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Pixels also won't be an issue as they don't have "GB" in that section.

Answer (score 2):

I'm little late to the party !

I was giving this a quick try with simple formula approach and was able to come up with something like this which seems to be working with the current set of sample data.

If your text is in cell A1 then give these formulas a try for extracting the relevant information,

[image]

[image]

1. `=LEFT(A1,(FIND(",",A1,1)-1))`
2. `=MID(A1,SEARCH("(",A1)+1,SEARCH(")",A1)-SEARCH("(",A1)-1)`
3. `=MAX(VALUE(MID(A1,FIND("GB",A1)-3,2)),VALUE(IFERROR(MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND("GB",A1,FIND("GB",A1)+1),0)-3,3),0)))&" GB"`

Answer (score 2):

Using Regular Expressions:

Assumptions:

- Phone Name starts at the beginning of the string and ends at the first comma
- Screen size is the first entry that starts with a number that might be decimal and ends with the `"`
- Memory is the **last** entry that starts with an integer number ends with `GB`
- For this, we will use the `Replace` method

---

```
Option Explicit
Function phone(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
    Const sPat As String = "^([^,]+).*?(\b[\d.]+"").*(\b\d+\s+GB).*"

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = sPat
    .Multiline = True
    phone = .Replace(S, "$1 $2 $3")
End With

End Function
```

[image]

### Explanation of Regex and Replace Patterns

```
^([^,]+).*?(\b[\d.]+").*(\b\d+\s+GB).*
```

Options: Case sensitive; ^$ match at line breaks

- [Assert position at the beginning of a line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sQuO.png) `^`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `([^,]+)`

  - [Match any character that is NOT a “,”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `[^,]+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.*?`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) `*?`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(\b[\d.]+")`

  - [Assert position at a word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`
  - [Match a single character present in the list below](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[\d.]+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
    - [A “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d`
    - [The literal character “.”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `.`
  - [Match the character “"” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `"`
- [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.*`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 3](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(\b\d+\s+GB)`

  - [Assert position at a word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`
  - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [Match the character string “GB” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `GB`
- [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.*`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`

$1 $2 $3

- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$1`
- [Insert the character “ ” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)
- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$2`
- [Insert the character “ ” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)
- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 3](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$3`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)